# Matlab : Can SOM and kmeans be applied to binarize time series data?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, cluster-analysis, k-means, self-organizing-maps

I found a similar question asked here [Determining cluster membership in SOM (Self Organizing Map) for time series data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128859/determining-cluster-membership-in-som-self-organizing-map-for-time-series-data?rq=1)

and I want to learn how to apply self organizing map in binarizing or assigning more than 2 kinds of symbols to data.

For example, let `data = rand(100,1)` In general, I would be doing `data_quantized = 2*(data>=0.5)-1` to get a binary valued transformed series where the threshold 0.5 is assumed and fixed. It may have been possible to quantize data using more that 2 symbols. Can kmeans or SOM be applied to do this task? What should be the input and output if I were to use SOM in quantizing the data?

`X = {x_i(t)}` for i =1:N and t = 1:T number of time series, `N` represents the number of components/ variables. To get the quantized value for any vector x_i is to use the value of the BMU, which is nearest. The quantization error will be the Euclidean norm of the difference of the input vector and the best-matching model. Then a new time series is compared / matched using the symbols representation of the time series. WOuld BMU be a scalar valued number or a vector of floating point numbers? It is very hard to picturize what SOM is doing.

Matlab implementation https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39930-self-organizing-map-simple-demonstration

I cannot understand how to work for time series in quantization.  Assuming `N = 1`, a 1 dimensional array/ vector of elements obtained from a white noise process, how can I quantize / partition this data using self organizing map?

http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/cluster-with-self-organizing-map-neural-network.html

is provided by the Matlab but it works for N dimensional data but I have a 1 dimensional data containing 1000 data points (t =1,...,1000).

It shall be of immense help if a toy example is provided which explain how a time series can be quantized into multiple levels. Let, trainingData = x_i;

```
T = 1000;
N = 1;
x_i = rand(T,N)  ;
```

How can I apply the code below of SOM so that the numerical valued data can be represented by symbols such as 1,2,3 i.e clustered using 3 symbols? A data point (scalar valued) can be either represented by symbol 1 or 2 or 3.

```
function som = SOMSimple(nfeatures, ndim, nepochs, ntrainingvectors, eta0, etadecay, sgm0, sgmdecay, showMode)
%SOMSimple Simple demonstration of a Self-Organizing Map that was proposed by Kohonen.
%   sommap = SOMSimple(nfeatures, ndim, nepochs, ntrainingvectors, eta0, neta, sgm0, nsgm, showMode) 
%   trains a self-organizing map with the following parameters
%       nfeatures        - dimension size of the training feature vectors
%       ndim             - width of a square SOM map
%       nepochs          - number of epochs used for training
%       ntrainingvectors - number of training vectors that are randomly generated
%       eta0             - initial learning rate
%       etadecay         - exponential decay rate of the learning rate
%       sgm0             - initial variance of a Gaussian function that
%                          is used to determine the neighbours of the best 
%                          matching unit (BMU)
%       sgmdecay         - exponential decay rate of the Gaussian variance 
%       showMode         - 0: do not show output, 
%                          1: show the initially randomly generated SOM map 
%                             and the trained SOM map,
%                          2: show the trained SOM map after each update
%
%   For example: A demonstration of an SOM map that is trained by RGB values
%           
%       som = SOMSimple(1,60,10,100,0.1,0.05,20,0.05,2);
%       % It uses:
%       %   1    : dimensions for training vectors
%       %   60x60: neurons
%       %   10   : epochs
%       %   100  : training vectors
%       %   0.1  : initial learning rate
%       %   0.05 : exponential decay rate of the learning rate
%       %   20   : initial Gaussian variance
%       %   0.05 : exponential decay rate of the Gaussian variance
%       %   2    : Display the som map after every update

nrows = ndim;
ncols = ndim;
nfeatures = 1;
som = rand(nrows,ncols,nfeatures);


% Generate random training data
    x_i = trainingData;

% Generate coordinate system
[x y] = meshgrid(1:ncols,1:nrows);

for t = 1:nepochs    
    % Compute the learning rate for the current epoch
    eta = eta0 * exp(-t*etadecay);        

    % Compute the variance of the Gaussian (Neighbourhood) function for the ucrrent epoch
    sgm = sgm0 * exp(-t*sgmdecay);

    % Consider the width of the Gaussian function as 3 sigma
    width = ceil(sgm*3);        

    for ntraining = 1:ntrainingvectors
        % Get current training vector
        trainingVector = trainingData(ntraining,:);

        % Compute the Euclidean distance between the training vector and
        % each neuron in the SOM map
        dist = getEuclideanDistance(trainingVector, som, nrows, ncols, nfeatures);

        % Find the best matching unit (bmu)
        [~, bmuindex] = min(dist);

        % transform the bmu index into 2D
        [bmurow bmucol] = ind2sub([nrows ncols],bmuindex);        

        % Generate a Gaussian function centered on the location of the bmu
        g = exp(-(((x - bmucol).^2) + ((y - bmurow).^2)) / (2*sgm*sgm));

        % Determine the boundary of the local neighbourhood
        fromrow = max(1,bmurow - width);
        torow   = min(bmurow + width,nrows);
        fromcol = max(1,bmucol - width);
        tocol   = min(bmucol + width,ncols);

        % Get the neighbouring neurons and determine the size of the neighbourhood
        neighbourNeurons = som(fromrow:torow,fromcol:tocol,:);
        sz = size(neighbourNeurons);

        % Transform the training vector and the Gaussian function into 
        % multi-dimensional to facilitate the computation of the neuron weights update
        T = reshape(repmat(trainingVector,sz(1)*sz(2),1),sz(1),sz(2),nfeatures);                   
        G = repmat(g(fromrow:torow,fromcol:tocol),[1 1 nfeatures]);

        % Update the weights of the neurons that are in the neighbourhood of the bmu
        neighbourNeurons = neighbourNeurons + eta .* G .* (T - neighbourNeurons);

        % Put the new weights of the BMU neighbouring neurons back to the
        % entire SOM map
        som(fromrow:torow,fromcol:tocol,:) = neighbourNeurons;


    end
end


function ed = getEuclideanDistance(trainingVector, sommap, nrows, ncols, nfeatures)

% Transform the 3D representation of neurons into 2D
neuronList = reshape(sommap,nrows*ncols,nfeatures);               

% Initialize Euclidean Distance
ed = 0;
for n = 1:size(neuronList,2)
    ed = ed + (trainingVector(n)-neuronList(:,n)).^2;
end
ed = sqrt(ed);
```

Comment: This paper (pdf) looks promising [Pattern Discovery from Stock Time Series Using Self-Organizing Maps](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.124.3646&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: Thank you for the link, but my problem definition is different. The paper uses SOM for dimension reduction, whereas I want to apply SOM to quantize the time series into multiple symbols / levels. For example, I have a time series `data = rand(100,1)` In general, I would be doing `data_quantized = 2*(data>=0.5)-1` to get a binary valued transformed series where the threshold 0.5 is assumed and fixed. It may have been possible to quantize `data` using more that 2 symbols. Can kmeans or SOM be applied to do this?

Comment: Maybe I am oversimplifying your question, but have you tried `kmeans(data,k)`, where `k` is the number of symbols? Because it sounds exactly what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that I might be misunderstanding your question, but from what I understand it is really quite straight forward, both with `kmeans` and with Matlab's own `selforgmap`. The implementation you have posted for SOMSimple I cannot really comment on.

Let's take your initial example:

```
rng(1337);
T = 1000;
x_i = rand(1,T); %rowvector for convenience
```

Assuming you want to quantize to three symbols, your manual version could be:

```
nsyms = 3;
symsthresh = [1:-1/nsyms:1/nsyms];
x_i_q = zeros(size(x_i));

for i=1:nsyms
    x_i_q(x_i<=symsthresh(i)) = i;
end
```

Using Matlab's own `selforgmap` you can achieve a similar result:

```
net = selforgmap(nsyms);
net.trainParam.showWindow = false;
net = train(net,x_i);
net(x_i);
y = net(x_i);
classes = vec2ind(y);
```

Lastly, the same can be done straightforwardly with `kmeans`:

```
clusters = kmeans(x_i',nsyms)';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have few doubts, could you please clarify? (1) Is `k =3` in the statement `symsthresh = [1:-1/k:1/k];` ? (2) When using SOM, are we first training the SOM? It is very hard to understand what SOM is actaully doing when using Matlab's built in function because I cannot know what the neighborhood size is, number of neorons, the Best matching Unit etc. So, it becomes difficult to relate the implementation to the theory. Is there a way to see the output of SOM which shows the association of data point to a symbol?

Comment: (3) The result of transforming the floating point values of the data `x_i` to symbols denoted by the variables `x_i_q`, `classes` and `clusters` using the 3 methods -- manual approach, SOM and and kmeans respectively are all different. How does one check which method gives the correct representation in symbols ?

Comment: The three methods differ only very slightly in terms of their results. You can compare the differences by transfering the classes to the same labels and looking for differences in clustering/classification. What is "correct" according to your judgment I cannot answer. With regards to your first question: I changed the variable name, sorry. I fixed that.

Comment: If you want to learn more about the `selforgmap` function, check out this [link](https://de.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/cluster-with-self-organizing-map-neural-network.html#bss4b_l-5).